# What do I do with the AR cards?

Tags: project-mirai-dx

Project Mirai DX comes with a pile of AR cards. I've been playing the rhythm game for a few songs now, and I have poked around the menu, but I am not sure what to do with these cards. Some of them say that they're character cards, others look to be songs, possibly videos of some sort. I'm really not sure how to use them.

How do I use these AR cards that came with the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the AR Cards, you must go to the AR Station in town: the purple building in the lower right that says AR on it. If you're in your room, you can press X to go to town.

Once at the AR Station, you'll be instructed to point your camera at a card. The game suggests being about 1 ft (30 cm) away, while keeping the whole card in frame. I'm not sure whether they work best straight on or at an angle, but the intent seems to be to use them at an angle as well.

For character cards, the game will add a 3D model of the character to the top screen, along with whatever scene you're pointing the camera at. They'll walk around a small area and can be instructed to pose with the A button, which will cause them to strike a random pose. You'll be able to take pictures, of course.

For song cards, you must additionally press A after the camera identifies the card, then a character will appear and start dancing as the song plays.

After a card is started up, you can push X to move onto another. Also, a couple settings appear on the bottom screen, like a size adjuster for the character.

There are 10 stamps related to the AR Station. 6 of them are for taking pictures of special poses, which you can get using the character cards at random after reaching a high enough friendship level to unlock that character's Pajamas outfit. There's 1 for using a character card, 1 for using a song card, and 1 for using all song cards (you only have to start the song: not let it finish). I think the last one is for taking your first picture, but am not certain.